GraphQLTestTemplate returning "Body is empty with status 401" for SpringBoot and GraphQL integration testing
I have been working on integration testing using SpringBoot + GraphQL following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdfEjn6xZx0 which I found pretty straightforward.
However, when I execute the JUnit test case, I am getting the following stacktrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Body is empty with status 401

at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:347)
at com.graphql.spring.boot.test.GraphQLResponse.<init>(GraphQLResponse.java:24)
at com.graphql.spring.boot.test.GraphQLTestTemplate.postRequest(GraphQLTestTemplate.java:142)
at com.graphql.spring.boot.test.GraphQLTestTemplate.post(GraphQLTestTemplate.java:137)
at com.graphql.spring.boot.test.GraphQLTestTemplate.perform(GraphQLTestTemplate.java:95)
at com.graphql.spring.boot.test.GraphQLTestTemplate.postForResource(GraphQLTestTemplate.java:116)

This is what I have included according to the tutorial:
pom.xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Integration Test code:
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = GraphQLEntryApplication.class)

public class PhysicianStorageContractIntegrationTest {

@Autowired
private GraphQLTestTemplate graphQLTestTemplate;

@Test
public void shouldGetAllPhysiciansByLocationId() throws IOException, JSONException {
    var operationName = "GetAllPhysiciansByLocationId";
    GraphQLResponse graphqlResponse = graphQLTestTemplate.postForResource(String.format(ContractIntegrationTestUtils.GRAPHQL_QUERY_REQUEST_PATH, operationName));
    var expectedResponseBody = ContractIntegrationTestUtils.readResponse(String.format(ContractIntegrationTestUtils.GRAPHQL_QUERY_RESPONSE_PATH, operationName));

    Assertions.assertThat(graphqlResponse.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponseBody, graphqlResponse.getRawResponse().getBody(), true);
}

}
Integration Contract Utils:
public final class ContractIntegrationTestUtils {

public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_KEY = "Content-Type";
public static final String MEDIATYPE_APP_JSON = "application/json";

public static final String GRAPHQL_QUERY_REQUEST_PATH = "contract-integration-physician-storage/request/%s.graphql";
public static final String GRAPHQL_QUERY_RESPONSE_PATH = "contract-integration-physician-storage/response/%s.json";

public static String readResponse(String responsePath) throws IOException {
    return IOUtils.toString(new ClassPathResource(responsePath).getInputStream(), UTF_8);
}

}
GraphQL request file:
query allPhysiciansByFacilityIdWithNoPagination {
allPhysiciansByFacilityIdWithNoPagination(locationId: 13613){
    totalSize
    physicians {
        firstName
        lastName
        middleInitials
    }
}
}

Response file:
{
  "data": {
    "allPhysiciansByFacilityIdWithNoPagination": {
      "totalSize": 4,
      "physicians": [
        {
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "middleInitials": null
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Chandler",
          "lastName": "Bing",
          "middleInitials": "K"
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Katy",
          "lastName": "Perry",
          "middleInitials": null
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Ross",
          "lastName": "Geller",
          "middleInitials": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

I was looking into the Web and I saw that it could be related to some security properties, I see that it is possible to disable it if I use a library like MockMvc, but not sure if that is possible using the GraphQL Test library that belongs to the SpringBoot module.
Any help or clue will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I can't remember for sure but I vaguely remember having an issue like this when I implemented my GraphQL Rest Template. Try this configuration for your TestRestTemplate. I dont know if it will solve your issue but I will say that this one works in my application (it's in Kotlin but should be easily translated to Java).
@Bean
fun testRestTemplate(environment: Environment): TestRestTemplate =
        TestRestTemplate(
            RestTemplateBuilder()
                .uriTemplateHandler(LocalHostUriTemplateHandler(environment, "http"))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        )

If this doesn't work I would suggest bumping your log level to INFO and try to see if there is anything that might be getting hidden by the log level.
